# getelementbyID on load returns null

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function that needs to find an element and set its height on load:

```
function setGround() { 

document.getElementById('content').style.height = '40px';

        } 


document.onload = setGround();
```

However the function returns "null" on load. Am I missing something obvious? Yes the element with that ID does exist.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.onload = setGround;
```

Remove the `()` or the function runs **immediately**, and then `document.onload` is set to the return of the function (which in your case is <strike>`null`</strike> `undefined`).

Comment: Alright it now does not return null, however the height style does not get added to the element :-s. Any idea why?

Comment: Ask another question. Remember to post your html along with it or else everyone might be alil lost ^_^ @SnippetSpace

Comment: @SnippetSpace: What type of element is it? Does it have a `block` display? Or is it `inline` like a `<span>`?

Comment: Try putting in a console.log, just to make sure that the JS is running, if it is, then you've got an issue with the line that's supposed to set the height

Comment: That line looks resurrected from a seriously ancient tutorial. Use document.ready instead.

Comment: the onload event occurs  when all content  has been loaded. That would be torture on the user. Use document.ready because ready occurs after the HTML document has been loaded. Note that ready is specific to jQuery, while onload is part of pure javascript.

Comment: @am not i am it is a "section"

Comment: @SnippetSpace: What browser are you using to test?

Comment: @am not i am | All of them. more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836675/set-height-using-javascript

Comment: @JohnMerlino:. That's `jQuery(document).ready` not `document.ready`, and it only makes sense to use it if you're already using jQuery.

Comment: @amnotiam if you read my above comment, i state that its specific to jquery. Bottom line is that code above is terrible.

Comment: @JohnMerlino: I did read your comment. Once again, that's `jQuery(document).ready`, or `jQuery.fn.ready` or `jQuery.ready` or `jQuery(fn)`. There is no `document.ready` from jQuery or in the native API. ...and no, `onload` is not "terrible".

Comment: @amnotiam you dont need to correct the obvious. This is a comment section, not a javascript interpreter.

Comment: It's a site to give users accurate and helpful information. Saying *"use document.ready"* is hardly obvious to a beginner. AFAIK, you were trying to refer to `document.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: For the record, a function with no return statement returns *undefined*, not null. It is *getElementById* that will return null since the element doesn't exist when the function is called, then attempting access to a property on that will throw an error.

Answer (score -3):

Ignore this, sorry

---

Technically when setting .onload, you should set it to a String of the javascript to run, so you should do

```
document.onload = "setGround()";
```

This might be your issue, it might just be a minor mistake that doesnt affect it, think it should help though

Comment: Eval is one of few JS methods that I will say is like licking Satan 100% of the time.

Comment: [How is eval evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) @AlexColeman

Comment: Apart from the fact that it does not work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/GGVNz/ (couldn't get it work with `document.onload`, probably because of jsfiddle, but it should not make a difference). The **DOM property** expects a function, not a string. It works if you assign a function reference.

Comment: Hmm. I was looking off here (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and it said that you should pass it a string; odd. Sorry

Comment: If you were using Ruby, you could use instance_eval and or class_eval, but of course javascript is not ruby, so stay away from eval in js.

Comment: Well there's the security issue (which I didn't used to buy but now understand better - it's about otherwise-limited-use SQL injections being able to do a lot more damage when the attacker passes stuff that will get fed into eval statements for every user) and a potential performance issue (you're creating a new instance of the JavaScript interpreter - I honestly have no idea how bad that is but it sounds like it could get brutal with heavy use). I'm sure there are rare exceptions of good use cases for it but for more day to day stuff I would definitely look for alternatives to eval.

Comment: Also there's building code with code in general being something to exercise healthy caution around. Powerful idea but typically done very poorly.